# Microsoft Graph Explorer returning empty businessPhones for Users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a special permission necessary to read the `businessPhones` of a User?

Calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myuseridaud@mydomain.com/` works just fine from when I use the Microsoft Graph Nuget package in my own code, but using the Graph Explorer, I always get an empty array.

Looking at the two requests in fiddler, the only difference I see is in headers (and my code uses authentication by AppId/AppSecret since login/pass authentication is not supported for applications).

What would make the Graph Explorer exclude this value?

Comment: Have you gone through the Admin Consent process for Graph Explorer? You need `User.Read.All` permission and you'll need an Admin to consent to in Graph Explorer before you can use it (the same process you want through for your AppID/Secret scopes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For graph explorer, you only need `User.Read.All` (Delegated)permission. Please check if the user has set businessPhones.

[image]

update:

[image]

Comment: Umm... interesting. I was using a global admin account but it appears as if User.Read.All is not part of the global admin. Do you know how to add it? i've done it for my own application where I can freely add/remove permissions, but for the Graph Explorer everything appears read-only in the AzureAD Admin panel

Comment: If you are a admin account, you should be able to modify permissions by using graph explorer.